# Default JDK used for android studio when STUDIO_JDK is not set

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am building a plugin for Android Studio using IntelliJ but it always shows this error when I try to load it on Android Studio. Unless I set STUDIO_JDK to the jdk1.8 path.

```
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: MyComponent :
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

So I wonder what JDK will android studio pick up by default when STUDIO_JDK is not set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question later. If you open "About Android Studio" you can see **JRE 1.6**. It means Android Studio is running on java 1.6 environment by default, no matter what "JDK" you are using for development. 
Of course there are ways to change this. You can put the jdk path in STUDIO_JDK and run Android Studio with that(initiate from terminal where you set STUDIO_JDK).
As a consequence of this, you will have to use JDK 1.6 when you develop a plugin for Android Studio so that it can work on the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

It says

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

you should try using jdk 1.8 with different major.minor version (other than 52.0)

Comment: some research lead me to this page [Unsupported major.minor version 52.0](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues/145)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio running on JRE 1.6 by default.I assumed that u have multi JDK and to change this JRE on Android Studio you need to delete/move default JDK (1.6). OSX :

`sudo mv /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk /tmp`

Finally check on "About Android Studio"